# Node FS readFile .zip incomplete

Tags: node.js

So I have a file called build.zip, it is 3546523 bytes and this file works properly.
Then I try to read this file with Node (v5.11.0) like this:

```
  const body = await fs.readFile('build.zip')

  return console.log(body.length)
```

But it returns a buffer with size of 3541543, so about 5kb smaller.
I tried with other encodings but that didn't help.

If I write the file with fs.writeFile then a zip file with that smaller size is created and doesn't work (obviously).

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Do you get the same result when *not using* `await` (e.g. using a callback instead or using `fs.readFileSync()` as a temporary test)?

Comment: Yep, that was what I was using first, had the same problem.

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to read the file before something else has finished writing it completely?

Comment: Well I changed zip library (was using archiver and now adm-zip) and now it works properly. I think the problem was that archiver was not completely finished writing after the finish callback (or more likely that I implemented it wrong somewhere). Anyway, changing zip lib works for me. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: FWIW when writing to file streams, you should always listen for the `close` event (instead of `finish`) since that indicates that the backing file descriptor has now been closed, so it is safe at that point to do whatever you want with the file.

Comment: Yea I think that may have been the problem, I waited for `finish` which I assumed was the right one (had my suspicions). Sadly the archiver documentation is very terse.